# Metric space -completeness

Tags: cauchy-sequences

> Show that $(C[0,1],\|\cdot\|_2)$ is not complete. For that consider the sequence $(g_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ defined below and show that this is not a convergent Cauchy-sequence.
>
> $g_n:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R},~g_n(t):=\begin{cases}f_n(t)~~~~~~~ t\in [0,\frac{1}{2}]\\1~~~~~~~~~~~~otherwise \end{cases}$
>
> $f_n:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R},~f_n(t):=\begin{cases}0, &for& 0\leq t<\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{n}\\ n[t-(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{n})], &for& \frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{n}\leq t<\frac{1}{2}\\-n[t-(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n})], &for& \frac{1}{2}\leq t<\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n} \\ 0, &for& \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n}\leq t\leq 1\end{cases}$
>
> https://i.stack.imgur.com/ew2Pg.jpg

Several hours ago I found this question while browsing through SE and it piqued my interest since $f_n$ looked kind of cool.

Anyway, someone got some hints? Or maybe the original poster found a solution and just deleted his post. If so I hope he sees this and shares his solution because I hate to go to bed with stuff on my mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume $n <m $. Then
$$
\|g_m-g_n\|_2^2=\int_{1/2-1/m}^{1/2}|g_m (t)-g_n (t)|^2\,dt\leq\frac4m,
$$
so the sequence is  $\|\cdot\|_2$-Cauchy. Now show that the limit is the characteristic function of $[1/2,1] $, which is not in $C [0,1] $:
$$
\|g_n-1_{[1/2,1]}\|_2^2=\int_{1/2-1/n}^{1/2}n^2\,\left (t-\left (\frac12-\frac1n\right)\right)^2\,dt=\frac {n^2}3\,\frac1 {n^3}=\frac1 {3n}.
$$

Comment: I'm sorry for the late response and also sorry for my silly question, but: I don't know how to show that the limit is the characteristic function of $[1/2,1].

Comment: Please see the edit.